# Modify Approval Status Value

Tags: workflow, email, approval-process, workflow-variable

I am sending an email through workflow and would like to indicate the Approval status. For example, I want the email to look like this:

> Your request has been **Approved** by the Administrator.

OR

> Your request has been **Rejected** by the Administrator.

HOWEVER, the email outputs:

> Your request has been **0;#Approved** by the Administrator.

How can I remove the **0;#**?

NOTE: I am aware I could create an email for each approval status, but I was hoping to do it in just one.

### Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Comment: Can you screenshot and send how you are getting the Approval Status? There should be a "Type" that you can fetch to "Lookup Value" instead of by String.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm new here so I don't have the ability to add images yet. What I've done is created a workflow that sends an email. The email then contains the [%Request:Approval Status%] in the body. But it shows up as either 0;#Approved or 0;1Rejected. I am using SharePoint 2007 so I don't see a lookup value in my actions. Cheers!

Comment: You could have an IF/ELSE branch that says IF [%Request:Approval Status%] CONTAINS Approved set variable to "Approved" else set variable to "Rejected" and put that variable in the email body instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid maintaining two different emails with the only difference being one word.

Comment: ... OR you may be on to something... If I do that and then create another step that sends the email... I will test it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: **It worked!** So simple. I created 3 IF/ELSE conditions to check the Approval Status and created a variable for each (Pending, Approved, Rejected), THEN created a new Step to send the emails! Thanks!

Comment: I posted the comment that helped you as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an IF/ELSE branch that says IF [%Request:Approval Status%] CONTAINS Approved set variable to "Approved" else set variable to "Rejected" and put that variable in the email body instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check below workflow actions

- Extract Substring from End of String
- Extract Substring from Index of String
- Extract Substring from Start of String
- Extract Substring of String from Index with Length
  Value stored in to a variable, then after that you can use this variable into your workflow actions.

Comment: Thanks Nagaraju, I forgot to mention I am using SharePoint 2007 (we are upgrading to 2013 this fall). I don't see any "Extract Substring" options.

Comment: In SharePoint2013 you can find more Utility Action in SharePoint Designer.