# SP2010 Custom Workflow Emails - Custom Values

Tags: workflow

I am modifying the default Workflow emails to make them more relevant to the content types and more user friendly. My question is, in the subject of the email I would like to put:

Subject: [Resource Request] {Title of Item} - {Approved/Rejected}

I've found a way to do this, but the hidden choice values seem to be showing up.

Subject: [Resource Request] {Title of Item} - 0;#Approved

EX: Workflow Choice Values
0;# Choice 1
1;# Choice 2
2;# Choice 3

Does anyone know of a way to remove the "Number;#" values?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here [Modify Approval Status Value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/modify-approval-status-value)

Just use an If/Else Condition for 0;#Approved and set the value to "Approved"